# C++ POINTERS (student * [n] gives the error that array type is not assignable)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // inputting the number of students
    int n;
    cout << "How many students would you like to process?" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    student* s[n];
    string tmp;
    double t;
    // entering each student details
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // dynamically allocating object
        s[i] = new student();
        cout << "Enter first name for student " << (i + 1) << endl;
        cin >> tmp;
        s[i]->setFirstName(tmp);
        cout << "Enter middle name for student " << (i + 1) << endl;
        cin >> tmp;
        s[i]->setMiddleName(tmp);
        cout << "Enter last name for student " << (i + 1) << endl;
        cin >> tmp;
        s[i]->setLastName(tmp);
        cout << "Enter GPA for student " << (i + 1) << endl;
        cin >> t;
        s[i]->setGPA(t);
    }
    double avgGPA = 0;
    // printing the student details
    cout << "Students:" << endl;
    cout << "---------" << endl
        << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << s[i]->getFirstName() << " " << s[i]->getMiddleName() << " " << s[i]->getLastName() << " " << s[i]->getGPA() << endl;
        avgGPA += s[i]->getGPA();
    }
    avgGPA /= n;
    // printing the average GPA
    cout << endl
        << "Average GPA: " << avgGPA;
    // freeing the memory allocated to objects
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete s[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Under the main function `student * s [n];` says the array type is not assignable to the line.It also gives an error that the expression must contain a literal. I thought I was doing everything right, but there was an error. What is the solution to this error can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

`student* s[n];` is a *Variable-Length Array (VLA)*, which is not in the standard C++.

You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) like `std::vector<student*> s(n);`.

Also add `#include <vector>` at the beginning of your code to use that.

Comment: Better to use `std::vector<student>` instead and get rid of the use of `new`/`delete` altogether.